# which “The Fly” movie is more accurate to the short story?

Tags: adaptation-comparison, the-fly

I have seen both the '58 and '86 movies of *The Fly*. I have yet to read the short story and am curious as to which is more accurate. How do the two movies diverge from the short story? Which one is the more accurate?

Comment: You can read the story itself [here](https://alancook.wordpress.com/tag/the-fly-by-george-langelaan/) and make your own assessment.  Think you'll find the '58 version tracks quite closely to the story.

Comment: That you could make into an answer

Answer (score 2):

Think the 1958 film is more faithful to the original short story since it was not long after and the 86 film is more modern and scientifically plausible.

Comment: i agree. the croneberg version has the sophisticated idea of gradually transformation due to genetics while the original, same as story, is sudden and static transformation.